# opencv: LNK1112 module machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

Tags: c++, opencv

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.7.0

I'm trying to build an OpenCV console app in C++ and am getting this error.  I've seen a bunch of posts about it but most of them are older.  I haven't done any C++ in 20 years and can't figure this out.

Comment: This means you are mixing 32 and 64 bit. The libraries you link and your application must be 32 or 64 bit no mixing.